# brew install rbenv Error: rbenv-rbenv already installed To install this version, first `brew unlink rbenv`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, homebrew

I am trying to install `rbenv` on `OS X` by following instruction from site [link - setup ruby on macbook](http://www.createdbypete.com/articles/ruby-on-rails-development-setup-for-mac-osx/)

when I try `brew install rbenv` I get below error

```
Error: rbenv-rbenv already installed To install this version, first 'brew unlink rbenv'
```

Here is the output from `brew doctor`

```
brew doctor 
Your system is ready to brew.
```

I tried brew unlink rbenv on  which fails with message `Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/rbenv`

Please suggest how this can be solved.

I have tried all solutions as listed below

`brew update`

`brew prune`

`brew link rbenv`

nothing really works

Comment: You could try `brew uninstall rbenv --force`. If that doesn't work, please add the results of `brew list` and `which brew` to your question. Also, have you ever installed rvm? That can interfere with rbenv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This, I was able to solve by thrashing all the junk files and folders related to rbenv still existing in the system; as `brew link rbenv` wasn't working

Use command below to find any `rbenv` `files/folder` still existing in the system.

`sudo find /user/ -name "*rbenv*"`

most of the issues could be because `/usr/local/opt` may still have folders related to `rbenv`

then `carefully remove` any listed files/folder using command

`sudo rm -r <folder-listed-in-result-of-above-command>`

then try `brew install rbenv`, follow any output from this command (which may suggest `brew unlink rbenv && brew link rbenv`) and you should be good to go.

I do not recommend file/folder thrashing this way as it could be risky however, to be frank, this is only what worked for me.